# Get picked time from ngx-material-timepicker

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8 and ngx-material-timepicker (5.5.3).

Now I wanted to access the chosen time from the input field with a button that just console.logs the chosen time, in the template I have:

```
<input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [(ngModel)]="time" [ngxTimepicker]="pickerA" [format]="24">
<ngx-material-timepicker #pickerA></ngx-material-timepicker> <button (click)="showTime()">showTime</button>
```

in the component I have:

```
time = "22:00";
```

and

```
showTime(){
    console.log(this.time);
  }
```

but when I choose a time with the picker, the input field gets a new value, but the ngModel seems not to work because it always console logs: "22:00" (the init value) after clicking the button.

How can I access the picked time correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Try to put [value] instead of [(ngModel)]

```
<input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [value]="time" [ngxTimepicker]="pickerA" [format]="24">
<ngx-material-timepicker #pickerA></ngx-material-timepicker> <button (click)="showTime()">showTime</button>
```

Comment: that shows the init value "22:00" in the input field, but when I change the field with the timepicker to, lets say 15:00 and then hit the button to trigger showTime() (which console logs the this.time variable which shall be updated with the picker) then it still shows 22:00 in the console, because this.time is not updated